# Is it bad practice to store contract addresses as state variables?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, addresses

So, here's an example.

Say there is a dapp that has contracts A and B, and B has a function that calls a function in A.
In order for B to access A's code, B store A's address as a state variable, as such:

```
import "./A.sol";

contract B {
     address a;

     function foo () {
          ...
          A(a).f();
          ...
     }

     function updateA (address newA) {
          a = newA;
     }
}
```

There may come a point where the code in contract A needs to be upgraded, and hence a new instance should be deployed. In this case, `B.update(newA)` is run, where `newA` is the address of the updated A contract.

I understand that perhaps a better way (or at least, the customary way) is for B to inherit A so that B has access to all of A's code. But let's just assume such a design is out of the question.

My question is, is there a flaw in this design? That is, is it bad practice to store keep contract addresses as state variables? I'm still fairly new to solidity coding, but I haven't seen any smart contracts that do this.